Mean and variance of Wasserstein 2-distance for sequence of normal distributions obtained from resampling
I am reading this article: The curse of recurssion. At page 8, I dont know how to calculate the mean and variance for the Wassertein distance (the relations 4 and 5), in this context the hypothesis. I really tried to understand it, but the calculations are getting worse. Here is my work:$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|\mu_{n+1}-\mu\right\|^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|\mu_{n+1}-\mu\right\|^2 \mid F_n\right]\right]
$$
where $F_n=$ is the history until $n$.
\begin{aligned}
     \left\|\mu_{n+1}-\mu\right\|^2 & =\left\|\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n+\mu_n-\mu\right\|^2 \\
    & =\left(\mu_{n+1}-\mu_u\right)^2+2\left(\mu_{n+1 }-\mu_{n}\right)\left(\mu_n-\mu\right) +\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)^2 
 \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
 \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_{n+1}-\mu\right)^2 \mid F_n\right]=&\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n\right)^2 \mid F_n\right] +2 \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n\right)\left(\mu_n-\mu\right) \mid F_n\right] \\ &+\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)^2 \mid F_n\right] \\
     =&\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n\right)^2\mid F_n]+2\left(\mu_n-\mu\right) \mathbb{E}\left[\mu_{n+1}-\mu_u \mid F_n\right]\right. +\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)^2 
\end{aligned}
Now,
\begin{aligned}
 \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_{n+1}-\mu\right)^2\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n\right)^2 \mid F_n\right]\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)^2\right] \\
    & =\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sigma_n^2}{M_n}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mu_n-\mu\right)^2\right] 
 \end{aligned}
Now,we want $\sigma_n^2$.
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_n^2\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{M_{n-1}} \sum_{j=1}^{M_{n-1}}\left(X_j^{n-1}-\mu_{n-1}\right)^2\right] \\
    & =\frac{1}{M_{n-1}} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_j^{n-1}-\mu_{n-1}\right)^2 \mid F_{n-2}\right]] \\
    & X_j^{n-1} \sim N\left(\mu_{n-2,} \sigma_{n-2}^2\right) \quad X_j^{n-1}=\mu_{n-2}+\sigma_{n-2} Z_j \\
    & \mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_n^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_{n-2}^2\right]+\ldots \\
    &
\end{aligned}
